# AWS ElastiCache Redis - All nodes in one AZ to avoid data transfer costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, availability-zone

I'm setting up an ElastiCache Redis cluster, however event when disabling the Multi-AZ option the nodes are being distributed across multiple AZs. I want them to be in the same AZ as my EC2 nodes to avoid data transfer costs. It also seems impossible to move existing nodes to another AZ.

Is there a way to have all cluster nodes in the same AZ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends. Multi-AZ is **required** for Redis with Cluster Mode Enabled (CME). So different AZs are also required and you can't change it.

But with **Cluster Mode Disabled** (CMD), you can create your cluster in even one subnet. For that you have to create your own [subnet group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/SubnetGroups.Creating.html) and choose it when you create the CMD cluster.

Comment: Understood, thanks @Marcin! By any chance, are you aware of the benefit of having >2 vCPUs in Redis 6

Comment: @numX No problem. Don't know a specific benefit for CPUs in Redis, apart from generic one - concurrent requests could be possible handled more efficiently in my view.